# Open Link in New Tab Not Working in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <ul id ="testing">
       <li id="first"  onclick="openNewBackgroundTab('first')">first</li>
       <li id="second" onclick="openNewBackgroundTab('second')">second</li>    
    </ul>
</div>

 function openNewBackgroundTab(type) {
     debugger;
     var a = document.createElement("a");
     switch (type) {
         case 'first':
             a.href = "http://localhost:25282/UpLoadFile.aspx/";
             break;
         case 'second':
             a.href = "http://www.google.com/";
             break;
     }
     var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
     evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
     a.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
```

This code works perfectly for **chrome** and **Opera** for opening link in new tab while **keep focusing on current tab**,but not on **Firefox** and **IE** .Kindly guide me.I googled a lot but could not find solution.Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to use javascript for openning a new tab instead of a simple link with target blank ?

Comment: I want to maintain my focus on current page instead on newly opened tab,which is the default behaviour.

Comment: The user has the power to open a tab in the background, so why not simply leave it up to them?